# Как поделить колонки?

Tags: html

Мне нужно поделить колонки на 3 ряда рядом...
Не могу это сделать)
Вот как я делаю:

```html
"<table>"
"<tr>"
"<td width=\"1500\" bgcolor=\"#c0c0c0\"><center>{0} </center> </td>", "[Основная колонка]"
"<tr>"
"<td width=\"350\" bgcolor=\"#c0c0c0\"><center>{0} </td>", "1пункт"
```

и.т.д!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть [генераторы таблиц](http://www.apsolyamov.ru/files/html-table-generator.html), можно выделить нужные колонки и нажать "объединить"